Does rolling back to a savepoint release interim savepoints?
I'm studying Postgres by reading the docs, and section 3.4 says this:

"Keep in mind that either releasing or rolling back to a savepoint will automatically release all savepoints that were defined after it.
https://postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html

Surely they mean "will automatically release OR ROLLBACK all savepoints"?
It would make no sense to release (which means commit) a savepoint that you're rolling back past, right?

You need to read RELEASE SAVEPOINT. Spoiler alert it does not involve committing, that is the responsibility of the enclosing transaction.

@AdrianKlaver - I will when I get there.  :)  Currently on "4.1 Lexical Structure".

Releasing a savepoint does not alter table data nor does it undo any work that is part of the current transaction: it just discards the information necessary to ROLLBACK to that savepoint. Any savepoints that were created after the released savepoint are also released.
Performing a ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT effectively restores the current transaction to the state that existed when the savepoint was defined; therefore, savepoints that were created after the ROLLBACK savepoint are released because the transaction is no longer capable of restoring the state of those savepoints.
Performing a COMMIT releases all savepoints.

I'm using this answer to restate my now-updated understanding in my own words:

Savepoints allow you to selectively discard parts of the transaction, while committing the rest.
You can define multiple named savepoints, rollback to one by name - and do so multiple times.
You can release a savepoint if you no longer need the ability to rollback to it.
Rolling back to or releasing a savepoint will release all later savepoints.


They don't mean rollback as that would undo whatever happened in between the later savepoints, which it does not when you just release an earlier savepoint.
The idea that release is a "subtransaction commit" is at least an oversimplification. You don't really need to release savepoints to have their changes contribute to the transaction. Releasing a savepoint means you just no longer need the option to go that far back in time, which implies you also no longer need to be able to go any less back in time than that.
If you're satisfied with the work you've been doing for the past hour, it's understood that you're also ok with what you did 15 or 20 minutes ago. Undoing the past hour, also undoes stuff from 15 minutes ago.
Automatically releasing the in-between savepoints makes sense: you can't rollback forward to a savepoint you just went past. Why keep it?
Consider this: demo at db<>fiddle
begin;

insert into t values(1);
savepoint s1;
insert into t values(2);
savepoint s2;
insert into t values(3);
rollback to savepoint s1;

Once you went back to s1, a rollback to savepoint s2 would mean going forward:

You're trying to undo what you did after you went back to s1 and instead re-do what you had done originally.
You're trying to replay s2 operations on top of what you just did.

There are ways either of these could be implemented, but currently that only works in one direction, and undoing an undo just requires a re-do.

The one thing I still don't get is why releasing Savepoint A has to also mean releasing Savepoint B.  If I have two bookmarks stuck in a book, I can remove either one without disturbing the other.  Maybe it's a limitation of PG's architecture, which I can accept - but logically, one should be able to design a database to allow random-access savepoint deletion if one wanted to.

Another analogy:  I start driving from San Diego with my buddy recording our progress.  When we get to LA I say "save that page, we might need to go back".  Then we drive to Vegas.  "Save that page, too."  Then Reno - at which point I'm now sure we don't need to return to San Diego, so I tell him to toss the SD -> LA page but keep the rest for now.

@odigity With the road analogy, think of it as documenting your path for someone else driving from San Diego. You go from San Diego to LA and tell your buddy "Hey note down where we are and how we got here". You go to Vegas, save your path and location again. Then in Reno. If now you throw away the notes you saved about how you got from LA to Vegas, you won't be able to compile the rest into directions from San Diego to Reno or LA to Reno. Nobody starting in San Diego can rely on these notes to get to Vegas or Reno, so they only keep those up to LA.
